# How can I Test this Android function?

Tags: android

I just started learning how to make tests, it really stressed me a lot.
Could you please explain me how to test this simple function? I've spend a whole day trying to make simple tests and nothing get well.

```
public static boolean isPortrait(View v){
        if(v.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 1)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

It has two ways of getting a View

- From Fragment

  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_authentication_login, container, false);
- From Activity

  View v = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.splash_view);

Thank you

Comment: can you show the input that you have test/try ?

Comment: You will need to mock the view.

Comment: I call the function in two different ways, from a Fragment and from an Activity:

In fragment:
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_authentication_login, container, false);

In Activity
View v = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.splash_view);

Comment: The method it's inside a Class that is not a Fragment or Activity. It's just a simple java class.